# Reversing the nibbles

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am trying to "build a new number by reversing its nibbles".

This is the exercise:

```
Write a function that given an unsigned n
a) returns the value with the nibbles placed in reverse order
```

I was thinking that all the 8 nibbles from the 32 bit unsigned should be placed in reverse order. So , as an example for the number 24, which is 00000000000000000000000000011000.
=> The reversed value should be: 10000001000000000000000000000000.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned getNibble(unsigned n,unsigned p){

    unsigned mask = 0xFu;
    unsigned nibble = 0;
    nibble = (n&(mask<<p))>>p;
    return nibble;
}

unsigned swapNibbles(unsigned n){
    unsigned new = 0;
    unsigned nibble;
    for(unsigned i=0;i<(sizeof(n)*8);i=i+4){
        nibble = getNibble(n,i);
        new = (new<<i) + nibble;
    }
    return new;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("0x%x",swapNibbles(24));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to debug it , and it went well until one point.
At one of the right shifts , it transformed my "new" variable into 0.

Comment: At _which_ of the right shifts? What was `n`? What was `p`?

Comment: That sounds like you did a shift to many.

Comment: `sizeof(n)*8` -> `sizeof(n)*2` (there are 2 nybbles per byte, not 8).

Comment: @PaulR On the other hand the OP does `i = i + 4` to skip bits.

Comment: Note that using the variable name `new` is a great way to prevent anyone from compiling C code as C++...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: my bad - I didn’t read carefully enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
new = (new << i) + nibble;
```

is wrong. There should be

```
new = (new << 4) + nibble;
```

Answer (score 4):

An approach that does work in parallel:

```
uint32_t n = ...;

// Swap the nibbles of each byte.
n = (n & 0x0F0F0F0F ) << 4
  | (n & 0xF0F0F0F0 ) >> 4;

// Swap the bytes of each byte pair.
n = ( n & 0x00FF00FF ) << 8
  | ( n & 0xFF00FF00 ) >> 8;

// Swap the byte pairs.
n = ( n & 0x0000FFFF ) << 16
  | ( n & 0xFFFF0000 ) >> 16;
```

Doing the work in parallel greatly reduces the number of operations.

```
          OP's       This     
          Approach   Approach 
--------  ---------  ---------
Shifts     24 /  48    6 /   8    32 bits / 64 bits
Ands        8 /  16    6 /   8
Ors*        8 /  16    3 /   4
Assigns     8 /  16    3 /   4
Adds        8 /  16    0 /   0
Compares    8 /  16    0 /   0
--------  ---------  ---------
Total      64 / 128   18 /  24
--------  ---------  ---------
Scale     O(N)       O(log(N))

* Addition was used as "or" in the OP's solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (void)
{
    uint32_t x = 0xDEADBEEF;
    printf("original 4 bytes %X\n", x);
    
    uint32_t y = 0;

    for(uint8_t i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i += 4)
    {
        y <<= 4;
        y |= x>>i & 0xF;
    }
    
    printf("reverse order nibbles %X\n", y);

return 0;
}
```

This could be made generic function for accepting all 8,16,32 bits numbers. But for now this resolves the bug you are facing in your code.

But I would point out ikegami's code is much better than this approach.